# Squared buffered polygon based on polyline

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, buffer

I'm using ArcGIS Javascript API to allow users to draw polylines and polygons onto a map. Now when a user draws a polyline, this should result in a polygon surrounding the polyline at a fixed width:

[image]

*(polygon here is handdrawn, but should give an idea of what I would like to accomplish)*

I can utilize the [GeometryService.buffer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-GeometryService.html#buffer) method, but that gives me a rounded polygon:

[image]

Is there any way I could achieve this? It doesn't seem the [BufferParameters](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-BufferParameters.html) object has an option for that. I was also considering using a convex hull *might* be a way towards a solution, although I'm not seeing yet how I could utilize it to my needs...

Does anyone have a solution?

#### Update

For now I have achieved a workable yet not ideal solution:

- Take the array of coordinates ('rings') from the buffered polygon geometry
- Loop through the array of coordinates and calculate the distance between them
- If the distance between two vertices is below a certain treshold then I know the coordinates are part of an arc.
- In my case an arc of 180 degrees consists of 49 rings, so I remove all rings from the arc except the 25th.
- Restore the buffered polygon geometry with the new, reduced set of rings

It doesn't produce the exact shape I'm after but for the time being this is sufficient:

[image]

Comment: I, I cannot exactly achieve what you want but have you tried looking at the generalize function of the geometryEngine https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#generalize ? You could then try to generalize your buffer

Comment: In general, I would say yes. Unfortunately in my experience it would also generalize points at the "straights". At least for my requirement it's paramount that the buffer polygon bounderies should be mostly parallel to the polyline

Answer (score 1):

This set of functions uses a similar technique to remove the arcs at the ends of the buffered line segments and create a polygon with squared off edges.

```
  private makeSquarePolygonEdges(polygon: Polygon, minDistance: number): Polygon {
    const squareRings: number[][][] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < polygon.rings.length; i++) {
      const measuredPoints: any[] = this.getMeasuredPoints(polygon.rings[i], polygon.spatialReference);
      const keepPoints: any[] = this.discardArcPoints(measuredPoints, minDistance);
      squareRings.push(keepPoints.map((p) => [p.x, p.y]));
    }

    polygon.rings = squareRings;
    return polygon;
  }

  private getMeasuredPoints(rings: number[][], spatialReference: SpatialReference): any[] {
    const measuredPoints: any[] = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < rings.length; i++) {
      let currPoint: Point = new Point({
        spatialReference: spatialReference,
        x: rings[i][0],
        y: rings[i][1],
      });

      let prevPoint: Point | undefined = undefined;
      if (i > 0) {
        prevPoint = new Point({
          spatialReference: spatialReference,
          x: rings[i - 1][0],
          y: rings[i - 1][1],
        });
      }
  
      let nextPoint: Point | undefined = undefined;
      if (i < rings.length - 1) {
        nextPoint = new Point({
          spatialReference: spatialReference,
          x: rings[i + 1][0],
          y: rings[i + 1][1],
        });
      }

      const prevDistance = prevPoint ? GeometryEngine.distance(prevPoint, currPoint, "feet") : 0;
      const nextDistance = nextPoint ? GeometryEngine.distance(currPoint, nextPoint, "feet") : 0;

      measuredPoints.push({
        index: i,
        x: rings[i][0],
        y: rings[i][1],
        wkid: spatialReference.wkid,
        prevDistance: prevDistance,
        nextDistance: nextDistance,
      });
    }

    return measuredPoints;
  }

  private discardArcPoints(measuredPoints: any[], minDistance: number): any[] {
    const keepPoints: any[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < measuredPoints.length; i++) {
      if (measuredPoints[i].prevDistance >= minDistance || measuredPoints[i].nextDistance >= minDistance) {
        keepPoints.push(measuredPoints[i]);
      }
    }

    return keepPoints;
  }
```

[image]